# Как соединить строку и число?

Tags: python

Как соединить в `print` строку и число?

Если например eесть переменная `num` в цикле, и эту же переменную нужно в этом цикле соединить со строкой.

Comment: что вы понимаете под "соединить"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В Python 3.6 появилась `f''` строка](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html):

```
In [263]: var = 50

In [264]: f'variable + 5%: {var * 1.05}'
Out[264]: 'variable + 5%: 52.5'
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй это:

```
>> print 'Foo', 123
Foo 123
```

Либо используя `format`:

```
>> print "{} {}".format("Foo", 123)
Foo 123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Distance to Sun: " + str(150000000) + " km")
```

Answer (score 1):

Да просто через запятую

```
 print("string",2)
```

> string 2

Answer (score 0):

`print "String", 1, "String", 2, "ETC";`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]